Resizing and rescaling touchscreenbuttons based on the resolution of the game
Does anyone know how to rescale and reposition the touchscreenbuttons under a control node?
I need to use touchscreen buttons because godot buttons does not allow multiple button presses at the same time whereas I'm creating a game where I need multiple buttons to be pressed at once. This is my current setup
Setup
I've tried putting touchscreen buttons under control nodes but it only changes the position relative to the anchors and not the scale.
